# Prove this matrix inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Let $W$ be $n$ by $n$ real symmetric positive definite matrix, let $V$ be an invertible $n$ by $n$ square matrix. Then the matrix $V^TWV$ is also symetric and positive definite. Now let $\|V\|$ denote the largest singular value of $V$. That is, the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $V^TV$.

Then, show that:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\|x\| = 1} x^TVWV^Tx \leq \|V\|^2 \min_{\|y\| = 1} y^TWy
\end{equation}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$ such that $\|x\| = 1$.

Let $y = V^\top x / \|V^\top x\|$. Note that $\|y\| = 1$ and that $\|V^\top x\| \le \|V^\top\| = \|V\|$.
Then
$$x^\top V W V^\top x = \|V^\top x\|^2 \cdot y^\top W y \le \|V\|^2 \cdot y^\top W y.$$

Comment: Why does $\|V^{T}x\| \leq \|V^T\|$ Hold? The second is the largest e value of $V^TV$ not of $V^T$

Comment: Sorry the second quantity is the square root of the largest e-value of $V^TV$

Comment: @jmsac $\|V^\top x\| = \sqrt{x^\top VV^\top x} \le \lambda_{\max}(VV^\top) = \lambda_{\max}(V^\top V)$

Comment: Ahh ok thank you!